# Starting my Java program for an event of the other

Tags: java, user-interface, jvm

I have a desktop GUI program written in Java by a third party vendor. This program has a number of frames and controls on them. Now I have a requirement to start my Java program when the user clicks on a specific button on a specific frame of that Java program. Is that possible anyway? I am working on Windows 7 with JDK 7 u17.
(There is a scripting language called AutoIt which provides this kind of functionality but I can not use it as it is reported as False-Positive virus by my anti-virus software, i.e. Quick Heal.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the code for the program?

Comment: AutoHotKey is a software similar to AutoIt, maybe you could use that?

Comment: It is possible. But without changing source code it is hard to implement, and hell as hard to maintain.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't modify the code of that program, I can write only my own program to do something.